# CSV file not opening with any app from notification

Tags: android, file, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I want to open a CSV file from notification tap (pending intent) which was created by my app with any application that supports CSV viewing. I am using Microsoft Excel in this case. I am saving the file in "Download" folder in external storage. The file is visible and openable from any other file manager app but when I try to open the file from notification some app crashes or says "Try saving the file on the device and then opening it" (Microsoft Excel). So my question is If a file manager app can open the file with that same app, why can't my app open the file with that app. This is the code I am using:

```java
public void showNotifications(Context context, String title, String description, String mime, File file){

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getPath()); //Tried both file.getAbsolutePath(), getCanonicalPath() too
            Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri,mime); //using "text/csv" as mime
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", "bla bla bla", importance);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_arrow_circle_down_24)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: You should use a FileProvider to serve your file and get an uri with FileProvider.getUriForFile() instead of Uri.parse()